# jQuery does not add values, but lines them

Tags: jquery, css, addition

This maybe is a silly question, but I am lost!

So, I am trying to change div height with jQuery by adding values, but they are not adding up, but lining. Maybe some of you have had the same problem?

My code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(myfunction);
$(window).resize(myfunction);

function myfunction() {
    var divH = $('.container').css("height");
    divH = divH .replace(/px/g, "");

    var innerH = divH + 130;

    $('.divRight').css("width", innerH);
}
```

For example, .container height is 100px, the output should be 230px (100+130), but instead it shows 100130

Do you guys have any idea why???

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to convert the string into a number using `Number`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you are concatenating string values, instead of adding integers. You need to convert the `height()` value to an int which you can achieve by using `parseInt()`:

```
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).resize(myfunction);

function myfunction() {
    var divH = parseInt($('.container').css("height"), 10);
    var innerH = divH + 130;
    $('.divRight').css("width", innerH);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! But I am still suprised, because I use this kind of script all the time and this is the first time it is not working. Division worked..

Comment: Division would have worked because the `/` operator would have caused an implicit conversion from string to int. The `+` operator is used for both the concatenation of strings and the addition of ints, therefore no type coercion takes place.

Comment: Thank you. You deserve a cookie :)

Comment: I love cookies :D Glad to help.

Comment: Do you maybe have any idea why variables are still lining up on resize?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It may be best to start a new question for that - including a working example if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert string into number **adding +** before string or use *number()* or *parseInt()*

```
 var innerH = +divH + 130;  // 230
```

Convert string into number:  **Number**(divH ),**parseInt**(divH );

**OR**

```
 var innerH =  130 + divH;  // 230
```

NOTE: Actually divH  is string ,when you adding this into number it will be concatenate not add

Answer (score 1):

Always use **parseInt** for numeric strings.It will provide the accurate result.And if you have to calculate in decimals then use **parseFloat** for this purpose.

```
var divH = parseInt($('.container').css("height"), 10);
```

or

```
var innerH = parseInt(divH) + 130;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a number to a string. If you do a `parseInt(divH, 10)` before you add 130 to it you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I this with this case you should use height, width function of JQuery

```
 function myfunction() {
        var divH = $('.container').height();
        var innerH = divH + 130; 
        $('.divRight').width(innerH);
    }
```